# Rebase on github branch

Tags: git, github, git-rebase

Say I do the following steps:

- fork some project, create a topic branch
- push that branch over at GitHub
- request a pull from that branch to the original project

However, I get some comments to improve stuff on the code.

- I fix up the code, do a commit
- Rebase to squash old commits

Problem is, I can't push it anymore to the topic branch over at GitHub.

What's the best way of handling this then?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Once rebased, you cannot just add new commits on the forked repo (since you have replayed those commits during the rebase, rewriting their SHA1), you have to force your push:

```
git push -f
```

And then re-do your pull request.

This is ok since nobody has yet cloned your repo and started to used your branch.

If that branch was already used, follow [that blog post](https://github.com/ginatrapani/todo.txt-touch/wiki/Squash-All-Commits-Related-to-a-Single-Issue-into-a-Single-Commit):

> **Important:** If you've already pushed commits to GitHub, and then squash them locally, you will not be able to push that same branch to GitHub again.
>   Create a new branch--like `100-retweet-bug-squashed` or `100-retweet-bug-rc1` (for release candidate 1)--and squash your commits there.
>   Once everything is squashed and ready, push the new squashed branch to GitHub and send your pull request to Gina.

Comment: Worth noting that any discussion on the original github pull request will be not be available in the new pull request.